# GTM API error vendorTemplate.parameter.eventName: The value must not be empty.\n

Tags: tags, google-tag-manager

I am trying to add a new tag to GTM on the page https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/api/v2/reference/accounts/containers/workspaces/tags/create.

In parent I use next value:
accounts/[123456789]/containers/[1234567]/workspaces/[1234567].

`*` - in `[]` value for example.

In request body I write next data:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "type": "gaawc"
}
```

All  time I getting the next error:

```
{"error": {
      "code": 400,
      "message": "vendorTemplate.parameter.measurementId: The value must not be empty.\n",
      "errors": [{
          "message": "vendorTemplate.parameter.measurementId: The value must not be empty.\n",
          "domain": "global",
          "reason": "badRequest"
      }],
      "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using `gaawc` tag type.

So there are some several required field in the payload.

You can not just send `name : "test"` in this case.

You need to specify the `measurementId`.

---

Go back to GTM UI and try to create a GA4 configuration tag. You can not save it without setting the measurement id. So the rule is same if you want to use the API to create tag.

---

If you are not sure what the payload should be.

The simple way is create the `tag` in the GTM UI.

And export it as json file. You will see the actual json for the tag.

here is an example for test GA4 config tag

```
{
    "accountId": "3853417116",
    "containerId": "9675477",
    "tagId": "6",
    "name": "test-ga4-config-tag",
    "type": "gaawc",
    "parameter": [
        {
            "type": "BOOLEAN",
            "key": "sendPageView",
            "value": "true"
        },
        {
            "type": "BOOLEAN",
            "key": "enableSendToServerContainer",
            "value": "false"
        },
        {
            "type": "TEMPLATE",
            "key": "measurementId",
            "value": "G-000000"
        }
    ],
    "fingerprint": "1691569014795",
    "firingTriggerId": [
        "2147479553"
    ],
    "tagFiringOption": "ONCE_PER_EVENT",
    "monitoringMetadata": {
        "type": "MAP"
    },
    "consentSettings": {
        "consentStatus": "NOT_SET"
    }
}
```